# JAR file creeping up the size of users folder

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver, profile

Hi I am running jar file after creating test in selenium, on windows. every time when i run it, the size of users folder increase
Why

> C:\Documents and Settings\MyUserName

before run

> 8.79 GB (9,438,803,475 bytes)
> 8.84 GB (9,497,837,568 bytes)

runing

> 8.81 GB (9,470,489,146 bytes)
>
> 8.87 GB (9,529,806,848 bytes)

stop

> 8.79 GB (9,441,708,575 bytes)
>
> 8.84 GB (9,500,758,016 bytes)

When it stop it left some bytes. So my hard drive will be full if it do same. 
how to stop it to "left bytes"

Comment: Probably some log files. You should find out what files those bytes make up.

Comment: It's the log file, the app is probably runnig on the DEBUG level. BTW your hard drive will not necessarily get full if the app properly configures the log to roll over and delete old files.

Comment: Meh.  Your temp folder is in there, it's gonna grow no matter what you do.  You're probably accumulating garbage in it.

Comment: Please up vote to my question I am no longer allowed to ask question due to down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be any specific case.

> You are taking screen shot of failed test cases and keeping them in same directory.
>
> You are generating log of test case execution and storing them in the directory.

And any other specific to your project.Have a look on them.Neither java nor selenium have tendency to do so.:)

Comment: I am just opening a web page with selenium not saving any thing

Comment: @DarkWish not you. Selenium is saving stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a selenium session is created, a temporary profile is created in the temp folder 

In newer versions of selenium ,as per my knowledge(**above 2.17/higher**) the temp profile is automatically deleted on closing the browser.

I am not sure of older versions because I used  **2.13 , 2.17 , 2.25 only**

Comment: Thanks for answer I am using 2.26 it is right it delete profile automatically but it left out some bytes there as you can see in my question's states